# CORS error in S3 image download in angular 6

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, cors

Trying to download S3 image in angular but always throwing CORS error

Angular code to download image

```
getImage(): void {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("test",xhttp.response,xhttp.status);
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/rajubhai/20190318ubuntu1904jack.jpg", true);
  xhttp.responseType = "blob";
  xhttp.send();  
  }
```

S3 Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Getting error in console
[image]

But in network tab showing 200 status
[image]

S3 image URL directly worked in the image tag.

```
<img [src]="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/rajubhai/20190318ubuntu1904jack.jpg"/>
```

But I want an image in blob type to do crop functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Issue from AWS S3 bucket side

S3 URL thowing CORS error when we append directory name after domain name.

```
xhttp.open("GET", "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/rajubhai/3c8898e3-74a0-49a9-a03b-480b3253906bcrop_image_.png", true);
```

Now change URL and append directory name before the domain name and it's working.

```
xhttp.open("GET", "https://rajubhai.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/3c8898e3-74a0-49a9-a03b-480b3253906bcrop_image_.png", true);
```